# Else statement inside Switch is an syntax error?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, if-statement

I am getting Syntax Error on the else statement in the following code :

```
switch(v.getId())
{
case R.id.b0 :      
    if(s.length()==1 && s.charAt(0)=='0');
    {  
    et2.setText("0");
    et1.setText("0");
    }
    else
    {
    s=s+"0";
    call(s);
    }
    break;
//2nd case and body
}
```

The Error is : `Syntax error on token "else", delete this token`

Does java not permit this?

Will I have to use the nested switch?

Or is there something wrong with my code itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if(s.length()==1 && s.charAt(0)=='0');
```

remove `;`

Comment: I didn't expect to get the `nice answer` badge for this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

```
if(s.length()==1 && s.charAt(0)=='0');
                                     ^ Remove this!
```

You're terminating your `if` statement earlier than you think you are...

Answer (score 4):

Remove **;** at end of if

Should be:

```
 if(s.length()==1 && s.charAt(0)=='0')
```